# Is it proper to reject this edit?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, rejection-reasons

I recently received a [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/318861). I thought the edit was helpful, as it was probably more appropriate than my original code. However, I felt that "it's more proper" was hardly a good explanation for using `Context` over `Activity`. I rejected the edit with the comment, "Please add a comment to state specifically why Context should used instead of Activity. This is something I want to know too."

Was this the right thing to do? Should I have accepted the edit? I felt that having the user post an explanation in the comments would help provide useful information, but was I going too far? Since it *was* a helpful edit, should I have gone ahead and accepted it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, it was the right thing. Edits should not be used to reply or comment on the post. If someone wants to suggest an improvement for your code, they should comment. Your code is intrinsic to your post. If it is modified, the question changes. Stack Overflow's policy on edits that change the post is clear. I believe you reserve the right to do as you did.

Comment: `Your code is yours` That's not completely correct on SE. Everything in here stands under CC-BY-SA, and in theory it's totally fine to edit code. But we apply the policy that changes in the code would change the meaning of the answer, and *that* needs to be discussed with the original author, at least in a etiquette type of way.

Comment: You're right, I've edited to fit that.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, it's perfectly alright. Your answer uses `Activity` and if another user feels that `Context` is more appropriate, they need to **openly explain why**, not hide the reason in the suggested edit where people might not even see it. *Then*, if you feel he's correct, you can edit your answer to reflect that.

Ultimately, he's radically changing your answer. *You* didn't say to use `Context`, he did. You don't even know why you might want to use `Context` over `Activity`, so it doesn't make much sense to make it part of your answer. Maybe he should have posted his own if it's so important and "proper."